# Using AFHTTPSessionManager in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, nsurlsession

While I do plan to switch over to `Alamofire` in the future, in the meanwhile, I'm looking to convert my `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclasess from objc to swift. I'm having some issues converting my custom `dataTaskWithHTTPMethod` method. the function overrides the `AFHTTPSessionManager.dataTaskWithHTTPMethod` so I could add some extra headers to the request and pass the response body into the failure completion closure.

```
@interface WebAPIClient : AFHTTPSessionManager
```

and the implementation function:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
                                   URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                   csrfToken:(NSString *)csrfToken
                                  parameters:(id)parameters
                                     success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success
                                     failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *, id))failure
{
  NSError *serializationError = nil;
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL].absoluteString parameters:parameters error:&serializationError];
  if (serializationError) {
    if (failure) {
      dispatch_async(self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        failure(nil, serializationError, nil);
      });
    }

  return nil;
  }

  if (csrfToken!=nil) {
    [request setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];
    [request setValue:csrfToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken"];
  }


  __block NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = nil;
  dataTask = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    if (failure) {
      failure(dataTask, error, responseObject);
    }
  } else {
    if (success) {
      success(dataTask, responseObject);
    }
  }
  }];

  return dataTask;
}
```

I mostly have difficulties figuring out how to rewrite the first section of the function. Dealing with `NSError` in swift and passing it to a function behaves differently and I was unable to use the `NSErrorPointer` replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your method would look like in Swift:

```
typealias DataTaskSuccessHandler = (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?, responseObject: AnyObject?) -> ()
typealias DataTaskErrorHandler = (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?, error: NSError?, responseObject: AnyObject?) -> ()

func dataTask(withHTTPMethod httpMethod: String, urlString: String, csfrToken: String?, parameters: AnyObject?, success: DataTaskSuccessHandler?, failure: DataTaskErrorHandler?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask? {
    var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
    var serializationError: NSError?
    guard let absoluteURLString = NSURL(string: urlString, relativeToURL: baseURL)?.absoluteString else { return nil }
    let request = requestSerializer.requestWithMethod(httpMethod, URLString: absoluteURLString, parameters: parameters, error: &serializationError)
    if serializationError != nil {
        if let failure = failure {
            dispatch_async(completionQueue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                failure(dataTask: nil, error: serializationError, responseObject: nil)
            })
        }
        return nil
    }

    if let csfrToken = csfrToken {
        request.setValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
        request.setValue(csfrToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CSRFToken")
    }

    dataTask = dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (_, responseObject, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error, let failure = failure {
            failure(dataTask: dataTask, error: error, responseObject: responseObject)
        } else if let success = success {
            success(dataTask: dataTask, responseObject: responseObject)
        }
    })

    return dataTask
}
```

I was not sure if the `success` and `failure` closures would be required when you call your function so I defined them as Optionals. If you never call the method without the success and failure handlers you can remove those Optionals and get rid of the `if let` when executing those closures.